# Rails Paperclip how to rollback only one attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Is there a way to rollback a specific Rails Paperclip migration?

I'm trying to rollback just one migration which is `avatar` but this doesn't seem to be working.

What's the best way to do this in Rails console?

**Paperclip migrations**

```
class AddAttachmentAvatarToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.attachment :avatar
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :users, :avatar
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the paperclip migration file here? You might need to manually edit the "down" to get what you need

Comment: @portforwardpodcast I've pasted the migrations

Comment: That seems like it should work, so I guess you should post the error your getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work for you? Run a new migration that removes the avatar.

```
class RemoveAvatarColumnsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    remove_attachment :users, :avatar
  end

  def self.down
    add_attachment :users, :avatar
  end
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You mean change the migrations on that file?

Comment: I would just use `remove_attachment :users, :avatar` in your current `self_down` method and do a rollback. IF you do that, do you get any errors? Btw, `drop_attached_file` is [vintage syntax](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#vintage-syntax)